# Storm BasicDRPC client execute

Tags: java, apache-storm

I am a beginner storm user. I am trying out drpc server in remote mode. I got drpc server started and configured the drpc server location in yaml file. BUT, I am not understanding how the drpc client code should look like:
https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter/blob/master/src/jvm/storm/starter/BasicDRPCTopology.java

Here is what I did:

1. Launched DRPC server(s)  (storm drpc command)
2. Configure the locations of the DRPC servers  (edited the yaml file. Added the local host name)
3. Submit DRPC topologies to Storm cluster - did this, looks like the topology is up and running.

But how do I get a client to call/execute on this topology? Do I need something like this?https://github.com/mykidong/storm-finagle-drpc-client/blob/master/src/main/java/storm/finagle/drpc/StormDrpcClient.java  ??  I tried but I keep getting this error:

storm/starter/DRPCClient.java:[68,18] error: execute(String,String) in DRPCClient cannot implement execute(String,String) in Iface
   [ERROR] overridden method does not throw TException

What am I missing here? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is [Storm DRPC Document](http://storm.incubator.apache.org/documentation/Distributed-RPC.html)
Maybe useful to understand DRPC Call :)

Just Like following code :

```
DRPCClient client = new DRPCClient("drpc-host", 3772);
String result = client.execute("reach", "http://twitter.com");
```

Create a client connection to DRPC-Server-Host: drpc-host at 3772 port .

DRPCClient called "reach" function using argument "http://twitter.com"

and return a string named result